# Нужна ли запятая перед "вне зависимости"

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

- Эта мода подходит любым женщинам **вне зависимости** от их возраста и комплекции.

или

- Эта мода подходит любым женщинам, **вне зависимости** от их возраста и комплекции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Оба варианта возможны.**

(1) Эта мода подходит любым женщинам **вне зависимости  от их возраста и комплекции** (интонация простого предложения, несогласованное определение не обособляется, пояснительные отношения не обозначены).

(2) Эта мода подходит любым женщинам, вне зависимости от их возраста и комплекции (обозначено пояснение, авторское выделение информации).

**О грамматике**

Это тема обособления **несогласованных определений**. **Обособление** таких определений делается в том случае, если определяемое существительное является узнаваемым лицом (например, именем собственным) или оно уже имеет определения, называющие **отличительные** его признаки.

Слова с неопределенным значением (человек, мужчина, женщина) обычно имеют необособленное определение, называющее их **отличительный признак**, а остальные определения являются **уточняющими,** например:   Из толпы особенно выделялся **человек с кудрявой головой**, без шапки, с расстёгнутой на груди рубахе.

**Дополнение (из Правил Лопатина)**

Примечание. Несогласованное определение может не обособляться, **если определяемое нарицательное имя само по себе не способно полноценно выразить смысл в данном контексте**: Впереди него стоял **мужчина в шляпе** (Шукш.) — слова человек и мужчина в данных контекстах требуют конкретизации путем указания на отличительные признаки (человек в очках и в странной шляпе, мужчина в шляпе).

**В приведенном примере выражение "любая женщина" подходит под оба случая.** С одной стороны, имеется согласованное определение, с другой — оно по-прежнему не в полной мере проясняет отличительные признаки лица. Отсюда — два варианта решения.

Answer (score 4):

**Обстоятельство**, **выраженное существительным с предлогом,** (*подходит КАК? **вне зависимости от возраста**)* **обособляется факультативно**, т.е. по решению и желанию автора.

Так что оба варианта пунктуационного оформления данного предложения возможны.