# О сочетании «вне зависимости от»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Это вопрос **общего характера** (конкретные предложения с этим сочетанием уже обсуждались).  Меня же интересует следующее.

1. **Это предлог?** Есть ли о нем в грамматике конкретная информация?
2. Обороты с этим предлогом **определительные или  обстоятельственные**? От чего это зависит?
3. **По какому правилу**  мы обособляем обороты в каждом случае (для определительных и обстоятельственных оборотов)? Всегда ли это решение факультативное или есть варианты, где выбор **однозначен**.  Интересно, что Грамота.ру иногда дает точный ответ, в других же случаях говорит о факультативности.

Примеры можно посмотреть в следующих темах:

1. *Эта куртка позволит девушке выглядеть привлекательно(,) **вне зависимости от погодных условий.*** [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467034/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-вне-зависимости](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467034/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)
2. *Эта мода подходит любым женщинам(,) **вне зависимости от их возраста и комплекции.***
   [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428526/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-вне-зависимости](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428526/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)
3. *Я различаю только два состояния, **вне зависимости от их качества: настроенное и ненастроенное.***
   [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453456/Отделяется-ли-сочетание-вне-зависимости](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453456/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Примечание. Я раньше отвечала на вопрос, но сейчас изменила бы ответ, выбрав точное, а не факультативное решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не всегда он факультативен. Когда оборот между подлежащим и сказуемым (тогда он вклинивается в структуру), значительная разница:
*Он вне зависимости от послЕдствий хочет в Москву.* || "Вне зависимости от последствий" здесь является самым важным в сообщении, поэтому не обособляется. В этом случае позиция малоудачна, поэтому распространён следующий вариант.
*Он, вне зависимости от последствий, хочет в Москву.* || Дополнительные сведения, которые вклиниваются в структуру и обособляются.

Словарь:
[image]

Как видим, **предлог в функции обстоятельства уступки**.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, замечания будут такие. 1. Желательно указать СЛОВАРЬ (я обычно только Кузнецова не указываю, так как он на Грамоте. ру).  2. Вы, как я вижу, считаете оборот только обстоятельственным (со значением уступки). А как насчет ОПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЬНОГО, есть ли такое значение у этой предложно-падежной формы? 3. Вы указываете, что структура влияет на обособление – это, конечно, справедливо. Но здесь (в некоторых предложениях), как мне кажется, есть ФОРМАЛЬНЫЕ признаки, по которым обособление делается сразу. Как вы думаете? P.S. Я внесла в вопрос  заданные предложения.

Comment: 1. Словарь Фрамполя. 2. Даже не представляю здесь определительной функции. Думаю, что в словаре это было бы указано. 3. В третьем примере "вне зависимости" относится к глаголу, а не к "два состояния". Формальный признак для обособления — распространённость, задумка уточнения (или если оно кстати). Если оборот в конце, то на это очень влияет распространённость не самого оборота, а основного предложения, что связано с необходимостью паузы.

Comment: 1. А что за словарь, его можно найти  онлайн?  Это словарь вводных слов?  2. Формальными признаками я считаю слова ТОЛЬКО, ЛЮБОЙ, так как оборот раскрывает их содержание (поэтому всегда обособляется). 3. А вот предложно-падежная форма относится (1) или к глаголу на правах наречия (всегда, вне зависимости от чего-либо),  (2) или  к существительному как несогласованное определение (любой предмет, вне зависимости от каких-либо факторов). Вот это я называю определительным значением. Как думаете?

Comment: 1. Онлайн версию нигде не встречал. Да, вводных слов: там не всё есть, но заметно больше, чем на Грамоте; там часто указаны случаи обособления, когда на Грамоте только не обособляется. 2. *...я считаю слова ТОЛЬКО, ЛЮБОЙ* — эти слова действительно влияют. Если только два, потому что вне зависимости, то да. Но там вполне можно и без обособления. А во втором примере влияние сильнее, там можно подставить "это значит, что". Но для таких раскрытий требуется тире. Но и там можно без обособления, если не выражать одно через другое, тогда оборот напрямую относится к глаголу, без какого-либо уточнения.

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что оно только к глаголу может относится (обстоятельство). В вашем примере подразумевается какой-то глагол (*берём, возьмём*), там прямо просится действие. Если определительное значение, то его можно и перед существительным поставить. Да и давайте проверим словарю, что бывает только обстоятельством.

Comment: Говорить, что лучше обособить из-за наличия каких-то слов, — не вопрос. Но не стоит говорить, что отсутствие знака в этом случае ошибка (автор ведь мог задумать то, что менее удачно).

Comment: Да, на этот раз не нашли мы общий язык — возражаю по обоим пунктам.  Тогда чуть позже отвечу сама.

Comment: С чем именно не согласны? Вы думаете, что отсутствие знака в этих примерах — ошибка? Это точно не так. А насчёт определения — кажись, можно, но желательно, чтоб перед существительным не было прилагательного: *истина вне зависимости от чего-либо*. Но такое крайне редко.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, я все-таки дам подробный ответ, может еще кто выскажет свое мнение.

Comment: Во втором примере подходит "то есть", а следовательно, тире, чтоб показать взаимосвязь. При запятой эта связь не будет выражена грамматически, это будет просто присоединение, о причине которого придётся судить читающему. А в третьем примере туманный смысл, из-за чего разобраться во всех деталях не получается.

Comment: Примечание. Словосочетания с оборотом в определительной функции могут не вызывать вопросов, но уже в предложении начинаются проблемы. Пример: *Это истина вне зависимости от чего-либо.* Отнесение оборота напрямую к существительному звучит не по-русски, а если отнести его к глаголу "есть", который подразумевается, то всё в порядке. Какая разница при чтении? При отнесении к существительному промежуток между словами "истина" и "вне" гораздо меньше, а при отнесении к глаголу на слове "истина" делается небольшое ударение.

Comment: Спасибо, но хотелось бы большей точности при грамматическом разборе и выборе решения. Я кое-что написала для ответа, но не всё там сходится.  Попробую задать промежуточный вопрос.

Comment: Пример получше: *Это решение вне зависимости от интонации.* Здесь уже отнесение к существительному звучит. Можно понять так, как в предыдущем примере: *это решение, а интонация не влияет на то, что это решение*. Тогда к глаголу относится. А можно понять так: *это решение вот такое, то есть такой тип решения*. Но здесь, в отличие от предыдущего примера, вероятен второй вариант (который вас интересует).

Comment: Я вконец запуталась. С определениями/обстоятельствами у меня проблем нет, там я придумала четкую теорию, а вот с обязательным обособлением – облом.   Некоторые слова (любой, каждый) способствуют обособлению, но не более того. Пожалуй, закрою я вопрос, а вам спасибо за участие.

Comment: Это да. Кстати, ситуация похожа на ту, что с Яковом.

Answer (score 0):

1. Нет это не предлог, это больше связующие слова. В словаре об этом сл-но ничего нет
2. Обороты? Раз вы знаете названия этих оборотов, то скорее всего и знаете определения этих оборотов. Я пошел в кино вне зависимости от плохих оценок. Можете
   попробовать понять определ. или обстояв., скажу по секрету может быть и тем, и тем
3. Однозначного выбора к сож., нет но все же интуиция Вам подскажет))

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, у меня такие замечания. Посмотрите  тему https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428526/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-вне-зависимости  Там даны два разных ответа (обстоятельственный  и несогласованный  оборот) Отвечающие вполне опытные, но вот интуиция у них разная. Обоснования они не приводят, но в таком случае как решить, кто из них прав.  Вы бы за кого проголосовали?  Правила обособления для определений и обстоятельств разные.

Comment: Грамота. ру называет сочетание предлогом, но это не точный грамматический справочник. Эта же служба дает разные ответы,  решая то однозначно, то факультативно.  Интуиция помогает нам выбрать решение, а само решение должно иметь  точное обоснование, иначе это будет только мнение...

Comment: Ваши оба ответа правильеы. Можно ставить запятую, если автор хочет этим что-то подчеркнуть, а можно и не ставить.

Comment: Если честно, я вообще не знал, что кто-то еще пользуется грамотой ру, в которой пишется, что можно использовать глагол "победю"

Comment: Я в этом не уверена,  есть признаки однозначного ответа.  Обороты названы по-разному, кто "правее"?

Comment: Более правилен Ваш ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Тогда я проголосую за то, что ваш ответ полезен. ;) Про Грамоту.ру. Ошибки бывают у всех, но в целом это авторитетная служба. Кроме нее, у нас только Розенталь и ПАС.